# Python: Unable to query user define list from MySQL

Tags: python, mysql, flask-sqlalchemy

I am using flask sqlalchemy. However, when debugging in command line, I found that `session.execute` returns error.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/scoping.py", line 149, in do
    return getattr(self.registry(), name)(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/session.py", line 978, in execute
    clause, params or {})
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 720, in execute
    return meth(self, multiparams, params)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/sqlalchemy/sql/elements.py", line 317, in _execute_on_connection
    return connection._execute_clauseelement(self, multiparams, params)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 817, in _execute_clauseelement
    compiled_sql, distilled_params
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 884, in _execute_context
    None, None)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 1108, in _handle_dbapi_exception
    exc_info
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/sqlalchemy/util/compat.py", line 174, in raise_from_cause
    reraise(type(exception), exception, tb=exc_tb, cause=exc_value)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/sqlalchemy/util/compat.py", line 167, in reraise
    raise value.with_traceback(tb)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 878, in _execute_context
    conn = self._revalidate_connection()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 241, in _revalidate_connection
    "Can't reconnect until invalid "
sqlalchemy.exc.StatementError: Can't reconnect until invalid transaction is rolled back (original cause: sqlalchemy.exc.InvalidRequestError: Can't 
reconnect until invalid transaction is rolled back) 'SELECT * FROM KLSE WHERE Stock in %(param)s,%(param1)s' [{'param1': 'SHELL', 'param': 'GENM'}]
```

My code as below: It is actually defined by user from an app. However, I make it easier by defining two stocks in the `stockList`.

```
from flask import Flask,jsonify,abort,make_response,request,render_template
from flask.ext.sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy

db = SQLAlchemy(app)

@app.route('/KLSE/watchlist', methods=['GET'])
def KLSEwatch():
    #for testing this example purpose
    stockList = ['SHELL','GENM']
    #use in actual application
    #stockList = request.args['stockList'].split(',')
    placeholders = []
    for x in range (len(stockList)):
         placeholders.append(':param'+str(x))        
    query = 'SELECT * FROM KLSE WHERE Stock IN ({})'.format(placeholders)
    call = db.session.execute(query,{placeholders:stockList})
```

For some reason, I have to use `db.session.execute` and query in raw. I try on MySQL,`SELECT * FROM KLSE WHERE Stock IN ('SHELL','GENM');`can get the correct query. I believe some sqlalchemy specific syntax has caused this.

UPDATE:
test on the solution from @wkzhu return this error

```
query = 'SELECT * FROM KLSE WHERE Stock IN ({})'.format(
    "'" + "', '".join(stockList) + "'")
call = db.session.execute(query)

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/scoping.py", line 149, in do
    return getattr(self.registry(), name)(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/session.py", line 978, in execute
    clause, params or {})
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 720, in execute
    return meth(self, multiparams, params)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/sqlalchemy/sql/elements.py", line 317, in _execute_on_connection
    return connection._execute_clauseelement(self, multiparams, params)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 817, in _execute_clauseelement
    compiled_sql, distilled_params
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 884, in _execute_context
    None, None)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 1108, in _handle_dbapi_exception
    exc_info
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/sqlalchemy/util/compat.py", line 174, in raise_from_cause
    reraise(type(exception), exception, tb=exc_tb, cause=exc_value)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/sqlalchemy/util/compat.py", line 167, in reraise
    raise value.with_traceback(tb)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 878, in _execute_context
    conn = self._revalidate_connection()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 241, in _revalidate_connection
    "Can't reconnect until invalid "
sqlalchemy.exc.StatementError: Can't reconnect until invalid transaction is rolled back (original cause: sqlalchemy.exc.InvalidRequestError: Can't 
reconnect until invalid transaction is rolled back) "SELECT * FROM KLSE WHERE Stock IN ('SHELL', 'GENM')" [{}]
```

Comment: Why there are `SELET`  (and not `SELECT`) in the logs? Typo?

Comment: @alecxe, sorry, copy the previous error. I have corrected with the right error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From [SQLAlchemy doc's](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/session_api.html#sqlalchemy.orm.session.Session.execute), try this:

```
from sqlalchemy import text

def KLSEwatch():
    stockList = ['SHELL','GENM']
    placeholders = []
    for x in range(len(stockList)):
         placeholders.append('param'+str(x))  

    query = text('SELECT * FROM KLSE WHERE Stock IN ({})'.format(','.join(map(lambda s: ':'+s, placeholders))))
    #query = "SELECT * FROM KLSE WHERE Stock IN (':param0', ':param1')"

    params = dict(zip(placeholders, stockList)
    # params = {'param0': 'SHELL', 'param1': 'GENM'}

    call = db.session.execute(query, params)
```

Comment: @vindex, try this piece of code and let me know how it did go

Comment: I am trying, but I am not sure why  `call = db.session.execute(query, params)` is invalid syntax

Comment: @vindex, check updated answer, there was an issue in SQL statement.

Comment: error change to `sqlalchemy.exc.StatementError: A value is required for bind parameter 'param0' (original cause: sqlalchemy.exc.InvalidRequestError: A value is requ
ired for bind parameter 'param0') 'SELECT * FROM KLSE WHERE Stock IN (%(param0)s,%(param1)s)' [{':param1': 'GENM', ':param0': 'SHELL'}]`

Comment: @vindex, My Bad, again SQL syntax error, I've fixed it, I've made changes in overall code, review it all

Comment: Finally it works! Thanks. However, you mention string.format is vulnarable for sql injection, do you know how to make it safer for teh current code?

Comment: Passing `params` in `db.session.execute` should make it safer instead of `query.format(params)`

Comment: @vindex, if you feel this answer helped you, then please vote and accept it.

Comment: So, currently the code is not vulnerable of sql injection? Just want  to confirm

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/133180/discussion-between-vindex-and-iron-fist).

Answer (score 0):

Two problems I spotted. You have two parameters named `param` in your query, which I believe causes a conflict. You also put `placeholders` in the execute statement kwargs, which I believe is incorrect (dictionaries cannot have lists as keys).

More info on how you're supposed to format params here:
http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/core/sqlelement.html#sqlalchemy.sql.expression.text

I would simply pass the parameters directly into the query string, and `execute` the raw sql itself:

```
query = 'SELECT * FROM KLSE WHERE Stock IN ({})'.format(
    "'" + "', '".join(stockList) + "'")
call = db.session.execute(query)
```

Comment: Queries in the form of `string.format`are not recommended as they are vulnerable to SQL injections

Comment: @wkzhu, your solution still return error. Please refer to the Edit part of the post